# Why Material UI uses different build config based on production

Tags: material-ui

My production build breaks, I want to know what is the need of doing build config setting based on production why not staging or development build work here?

Comment: import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
    dangerouslyUseGlobalCSS: false,
    productionPrefix: 'c',
});                                                       Is it the best practices to solve this?

Comment: Any log errors when in development ?

Comment: Yes, design breaks. its resolved with above fix.